# How to draw multiple squares in a specific pattern in Java?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw 8 red squares in a specific pattern in java.

And I am expecting an output like this:
[Alteration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W78EL.png)

And this is what I have tried so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Alteration {
    private int xGrid;
    private int yGrid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Alteration a = new Alteration();
        a.display();
    }

    public void display() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Alteration");

        Background bg = new Background();

        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bg);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                bg.repaint();
                xGrid += 50;
                yGrid += 50;

            }

            yGrid = 0;
        }
    }

    class Background extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(xGrid, yGrid, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I compile the code and run it, I only see one red square at the position of (400, 0)

That was not what I expected to output and I dont know why. I've done plenty of research and I still cannot find the correct answer to my problem, can anyone help?

EDIT: I added a code in the paintComponent method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(xGrid, yGrid, 50, 50);
    System.out.println(xGrid+" "+yGrid);
}
```

Output (in the command prompt): `400 0`

The double for loop runs 8 loops in total.

so `bg.repaint()` is called 8 times.

However the command prompt prints only 1 line.

I'm confused by this, why does the command prompt only print 1 line despite the fact that the paintComponent method was called 8 times?

Comment: Your `paintComponent` only paints one square, you'd better make a list of coordinates available to this method, so that it paints all squares.